# AngularJS Unit Test Error dependence

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I create a very small project to test the **unit test** in **AngularJS**. The test work until I try to include the **dependence restangular**. Why it generates **conflicts**?. Files:

**karma.conf.js**

```
files: [
 'lib/angular.js',
 'lib/angular-route.js',
 'lib/angular-mocks.js',
 'lib/angular-cookies.js',
 'lib/angular-md5.js',
 'lib/restangular.js',
 'app.js',
 'tests/app.spec.js'
]
```

**app.js**

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
 'ngRoute',
 'ngCookies',
 'angular-md5',
 'restangular' //This generate ERROR!
]);
```

**app.spec.js**

```
describe('PhoneListController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));
  beforeEach(module('ngRoute'));
  beforeEach(module('angular-md5'));
  beforeEach(module('restangular')); //This generate ERROR!

  it('should...', inject(function($controller) {
    var scope = {};
    var ctrl = $controller('PhoneListController', {$scope: scope});
    expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
  }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you trying to load restangular. Then you might be getting error like 
Faild to instantiate module restangular due to `(_'underscore.js')` is undefined. The `'_'(undescore)` javascript utility library that Restangular uses and depending on it. Include `(_'underscore.js')` library before the angular js in your template.

Here is your working jsfiddle code please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/chhitij92/x67u4Ldu/ In external resource I Included `'_'(undescore)` **cdn** after this its working.